# ElasticSearch illegal_argument_exception for client.bulk() Node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I try to send data to ES and I was using POST request to send data line by line and it worked fine with small files.

When I changed to use client.bulk(), I keep getting the following error message:

```
"status": 400,
"error":
{
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse [target_status_code]",
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "For input string: \"-\""
    }
}
```

I noticed that after I use bulk, the type of target_status_code field has changed from string to number and many keyord fields are gone.

I only modified the sending request function so I don't understand why it doesn't work when using bulk.

Comment: I found the reason.

Comment: What was the reason?

Comment: It could be anything, so at first, you should check all fields' types https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_bulk

Comment: could you post a sample of how you did it?